# action calling repeatedly using partialviews through list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views

I have list of resumes on which jobseeker can add note and send message to each of them. So I created partial view of resume. I used `Ajax.Beginform` method in partial views. On partial view there is submit option. Now when I call a specific resume partial view it calls the action and perform the job but not single time it repeats for each resume item. So why is the action called repeatedly? My View is here

```
@model NoteViewModel
<script src="~/Content/scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<div class="app-tab-content" id="two-1">

    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddNote","Employer",new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "result" }))
    { 
        if(@Model!=null)
        { 
        <input type="text" name="note" />
        <input type="hidden" value="@Model.Res_id" name="res" />
        <input type="hidden" value="@Model.Job_id" name="job" />

        @*<button type="submit" value="AddNote"></button>*@

        <input type="submit" id="AddNote" value="Add Note" />
        }
    }
    <div id="result">
       @if(ViewBag.NoteMessage!=null)
       { 
         <p>ViewBag.NoteMessage</p>
       }
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is an action method

```
public ActionResult AddNote(string note, int? res, int? job)
{
    jpc_resume_job jr = db.jpc_resume_job.Where(m => m.job_id == job && m.resume_id == res).FirstOrDefault();
   
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        
        jr.note = note;
        db.Entry(jr).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        ViewBag.NoteMessage = "Note Added Successfully";
        return PartialView("Addnote");
    }
    ViewBag.NoteMessage = "Note Not Added Successfully";
    return PartialView("Addnote");
}
```

I am calling this in searchresume view like this:

```
Foreach(var item in resume)
{
    @Html.Partial("Addnote");
}
```

An image is attached for what exactly I want

[image]

Comment: Sorry ! What is the problem you are facing ? When you submit the form for one item(resume) in the list of items, It submits data for all items in the list to `AddNote` ?

Comment: I believe each instance of the partial view would need a unique update target Id,(UpdateTargetId ="result") where is this result element.

Comment: @Sam.C ho would i be able to do that please be more specific

Comment: @Shyju No it do it for only that resume but number of iterations are equal to twice of number of resumes

Comment: what iterations are you talking about ? Sorry i am still not following you.

Comment: @Shyju as i discuessed above that ii am calling partial views through itereation of list to be me clear when i m calling partial view  foreacht(item in jpc_resume)PartialView("Addnote");

Comment: i am calling partial view for each resume i.e. foreach(item in resume){foreacht(item in jpc_resume)PartialView("Addnote");}